# Intersection of two querysets in django

Tags: python, django

I can't do an AND on two querysets.  As in, q1 & q2.  I get  the empty set and I do not know why.  I have tested this with the simplest cases.  I am using django 1.1.1

I have basically objects like this:

```
item1
   name="Joe"
   color = "blue"
item2
   name="Jim"
   color = "blue"
   color = "white"
item3
   name="John"
   color = "red"
   color = "white"
```

Is there something weird about having a many-to-many relationship or what am I missing?

`queryset1 = Item.objects.filter(color="blue")`
this gives (item1, item2)

`queryset2 = Item.objects.filter(color="white")`
this gives (item2, item3)

`queryset1 & queryset2` gives me the empty set `[]`
The OR operator works fine (I'm using   "`|`"   )

Why is this so?

Comment: Could you add model classes for Item and Color?

Comment: Attributes can only have a single value, so there's no possible way to have objects like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
qs = Item.objects.filter(color__in=['blue','white'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.objects.filter(color="blue").filter(color="white")
```